# Processing IRC messages using regex

Tags: regex

`:nick!~user@cloak COMMAND argument argument argument :argument with spaces in it`

I'm trying to match the above, capturing nick, user, cloak, and all arguments. A special "trailing" argument may be preceded by a colon, in which case, all characters including whitespace are a part of the argument. The "trailing" argument may also be the only argument. [RFC probably explains this concept better than me.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-2.3)

This is the expression I've tried:
`:(.+)!~(.+)@(.+?) (.+?) (.+?)+? ((?:: ).+)?`

According to regexr.com, this is what matches:

1. nick
2. user
3. cloak
4. COMMAND
5. t
6. (blank)

This is what I want to match:

1. nick
2. user
3. cloak
4. COMMAND
5. argument
6. argument
7. argument
8. argument with spaces in it

How can I modify the above expression so that it matches what I would like it to match?

Comment: The language you're using matters, as well as what a string without the "special argument" looks like. Are there trailing spaces. Likewise you should have an example with only the "special argument"

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't make a regex with an arbitrary number of groups; you'll have to match `argument argument argument` in one group and then split it later.

That being said, this [should work for your purposes](https://regex101.com/r/PPZGSQ/1):

```
^:([^!]+)!~([^@]+)@([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ((?:[^ :]| (?!:))*)(?: ?:(.+))?$
```

You'll note I made a could of tweaks. Notably, rather than matching anything (`.`) with a lazy quantifier (`+?`) followed by a delimiter (`!`), I matched for all non-delimiter characters with a greedy quantifier (`[^!]*`). Arguably it's a stylistic choice but I feel like it made this regex easier to read. Also, I added `^` and `$` for the start and end of the string; obviously if that doesn't match your use-case just take them out.

So down to the explanation. Most of the regex is functionally the same, so I'll just focus on `((?:[^ :]| (?!:))*)(?: ?:(.+))?`:

```
(                         # group 5: "argument argument argument"
  (
    ?:[^ ]| (?!:)         # a non-space-or-: OR a space not followed by a :
  )*                      # 0 or more times
)
 ?                        # optional space after the arguments
(?:                       # prefix
   ?:                     # optional space followed by :
   (.+)                   # capture group 6: "argument with spaces in it"
)?                        # 0 or 1 times
```

Notes:

1. I admit I only skimmed the RFC link, but it looks like more than one space can be used as a delimiter, so you might want to change those to `+`.
2. This will match an empty arguments list, and won't match an empty prefix (but *will* match if there's no prefix at all; aka if there's no trailing colon). Not sure if this is what you want.
3. I've assumed you can use lookaheads. Please specify what language/tool you're using so we can know what functionality is available to you.